# When is recycler view not offerning any benefit?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

If I have a vertical arrangement of layouts and some of them are horizontal lists of layouts, if these layouts either the vertical ones or the ones in the horizontal lists have **completely** different kind of designs which means that the can’t be reused based on the type in a viewholder/adapter, does it mean that using a RecyclerView offer no benefit?

Comment: Likely you are right, but still probably it makes sense not to keep all the views in memory, if there is a lot of them. If you will keep all them in memory (in case if there are too many of them) you risk to get OOM

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko:So basically the inflated views will be recycled but not reused? So that would be the only benefit? But GC would be very running a lot right?

Comment: I have used a Vertical RecyclerView with each row consisting of a Horizontal RecyclerView (think Netflix kind of layout).  Recycler Views in my case were vital for memory management due to each delegate of the horizontal views consisting of an image and text.  I did also have different adapters being used in each row based on the content type requirements.

Comment: @teh_raab:But if I got you, the horizontal views in your use case had the same layout so they could be reused in the shared pool right?

Comment: @Jim That is correct.  I see what you're saying now.